# Use of Map (Collection) in Lightning Component JS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I'm preparing a Map and doing some operations

`var tempParentMap = new Map();`

`tempParentMap[key] = someList;` This code works when I iterate through `forEach` loop
Like:

```
Object.keys(tempParentMap).forEach(function(key) {
   //Do Something
});
```

But when I'm doing this-  `tempParentMap.set(key, someList);` The Map doesn't let me iterate through. The `for` loop is breaking and doesn't go inside. Also I noticed that when I use `set` method of Map it gives me `Array` of Map. It gives me something like below:

```
[[Entries]]: Array(3)
0: {"01t1b0000018M1uAAE" => Proxy}
1: {"CardProcessing" => Proxy}
2: {"01t1b0000018M2EAAU" => Proxy}
```

The Iterations which are failing is as below:

```
for(let key in tempParentMap){ // Doen't go inside, it breaks and exit the loop. I'm guessing this is because, the `tempParentMap` is an Array of Map.
    //Do Something.
}
//Same happens with below code as well
Object.keys(tempParentMap).forEach(function(key) {
   //Do Something
});
```

Just trying to understand whats happening here? If anyone would be able to explain that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the following as your for loop:

```
for(let key of tempParentMap.keys()){ 
   console.log(key);
   console.log(tempParentMap[key];
}
```

Or

```
tempParentMap.forEach(function(value, key) {
   console.log(key + ’-’ + value);
});
```

Comment: The second one seems to be working but the first one is failing in the same way as it is failing for others. But still not clear why this is happening?

Comment: @SFDCMafia-VIC try to change in the first one from ’in’ to ’of’ as I've just edited.

Comment: @SFDCMafia-VIC does it work?

Comment: Partially, Now it is iterating and going inside the for loop, but the value is null and the key has value. I just want to understand why this is happening, do you have any insights?